# Properties of a cadlag continuous martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

So I get a little confused when it comes to trying to extend discrete time to continuous time martingales. For example I am unsure how to prove the following: 
If $D_n=\lbrace k2^{-n} \vert k \in Z\rbrace $ then for a cadlag martingale $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ the following is true
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{t \in D_n} \vert X_t \vert=\sup_{t\geq 0} \vert X_t\vert .$$
Do I have to use that $D= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ is dense in the real numbers? How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 5):

If you fix $\omega\in \Omega$, the sample path $t\mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is a cadlag function. So the problem reduces to show that for a cadlag function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{t\in D_n}|f(t)|=\sup_{t\ge 0}|f(t)|.  \quad (*)
$$

First, by the denseness of $D$ and the cadlag property of $f$, for each
$m\in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$$
\max_{t\in D_n\cap[0,m]}|f(t)|\to \sup_{t\in[0,m]}|f(t)|.   \quad (**)
$$

Then since both sides of $(**)$ are non-decreasing in $m$ and the LHS is non-decreasing in $n$ (for fixed $m$) we may send $m\to \infty$ to get $(*)$.